# The script is not processed when using "requests_html"

Tags: python, jquery, python-3.x, python-requests-html

When starting the render, it is necessary that the script is executed. My code looks something like this:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
headers = {'accept': '*/*',
           'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW32) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36'}
url = "MY_URL"
script="""
window.onload = function(){
$('select[name="SELECT_NAME"] option[value=1]').prop('selected', true);
$('input[class="BTN_CLASS"]').click();
}
"""
r.html.render(script=script, reload=False, keep_page=True,timeout = 15, sleep = 10)
print(r.html.html)
```

If you run the script lines in the browser console, they perform the task, and the script after rendering does not seem to be executed at all. For example, when you click on the button, even with incorrect data, a unique text appears, however r.html.html outputs the text when the page loads normally, without executing the script.

Answer (score 0):

Replaced "window.onload = function()" with "() =>" and the program started working.